# Why my code removes a checkbox control on the first setInterval call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the following code remove the `checkbox` control on the first `setInterval` call?

```
let autorefreshLabel = $('<label/>', {
    text: 'Atuorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...'
});
let autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox'
});
autorefreshLabel.prepend(autorefreshCheckbox);
$('#some-id').append(autorefreshLabel);

setInterval(function() {
    autorefreshTimer -= 1;
    autorefreshLabel.text('Atuorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what you've told it to do. You've put the checkbox **inside** the label, and in the `setInterval` callback you've used the `text` function to completely replace all contents of that label with the given text.

If you want to replace the text without replacing the checkbox, using jQuery the simplest thing is to use a span for the text:

```
let autorefreshLabel = $('<label/>', {
    html: '<span>Atuorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...</span>'
});
let autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox'
});
autorefreshLabel.prepend(autorefreshCheckbox);
$('#some-id').append(autorefreshLabel);
```

then in the callback:

```
autorefreshLabel.find("span").text(
  'Autorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...'
);
```

Or you could put the checkbox back after removing it:

```
autorefreshLabel.find("span").text(
  'Autorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...'
).prepend(autorefreshCheckbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you set the `text()` of the `label` you created, which overwrites all the existing content of that element. You could use `append()` instead.

```
setInterval(function() {
    autorefreshLabel.append('Autorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...');
}, 1000);
```

To avoid appending a new string on each iteration of the timer you could create another element within the `label` of which you can then set the text:

```
let autorefreshLabel = $('<label/>');
let autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox'
}).appendTo(autorefreshLabel);
let autorefreshText = $('<span />').appendTo(autorefreshLabel);

$('#some-id').append(autorefreshLabel);

var autorefreshTimer = 100;
setInterval(function() {
    autorefreshTimer -= 1;
    autorefreshText.text('Autorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...');
}, 1000);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ur19o003/)